# Can non-classes be autoloaded like spl_autoload_register?

Tags: php, include

I'm looking for a more elegant way to load the required include files for a page than manually adding them individually.

I thought this could be done with the spl_autoload_register which runs an anonymous function/closure or a specified function that is defined by the user and loads the class based on its name being called. As this function is triggered by the 'new' keyword used to create an instance of a class it doesn't work for non-class includes. I assume it will not work for classes that have static functions and vars either.

It seems that the options are:

Create a manual list for each page or something like an array that has the filenames of included files that are loaded by a function that loops through them. This is slow and prone to errors.

Creating a master includes file that has include/require commands for all the files that might be needed. Inefficient as files that may not be needed are also loaded, using server resources.

Is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Kw

Comment: `spl_autoload_register` is triggered evrytime a class is first time used. No madder if by `new` or called static and also if you do `class_exists()` with autoload parameter set to true.

Comment: `Is there a better way to do this?` Go for real OOP and you will never use 'include/require' again (only at 2 or 3 points, in the `spl_autoloader`, when laoding config files or loading/fetching templates). Try to make everthing without global functions/variables and/or global code.